# Strange character intercepted between strcat callc

Tags: c, char, append, strcat

I'm working with C in CentOS6.

When I use strcat, it puts strange characters between strings such as

'H', 'P', '@'.

Unfortunately, I cannot show my full source, because it is corporate property.

```
sprintf(tmp, "{\"vod\":{\"con_id\":\"%s\",\"thumbnails\":[", con_id);

        strcpy(json,tmp);
        char cmd[MAX];
        char innerjson[MAX_JSON];
        int thumb_idx;

        for(thumb_idx = 0; thumb_idx < thumb_cnt; thumb_idx++){

                pos_second += interval;
                sprintf(tmp,"{\"thumb_idx\":\"%d\", \"thumb_image\": \"thumbnail_%d.jpg\", \"position_t\":\"%d\"}", thumb_idx, thumb_idx, pos_second);

                if(thumb_idx != thumb_cnt-1)
                {
                        strcat(tmp, ", ");
                        strcat(innerjson, tmp);
                }else
                        strcat(innerjson,tmp);
                }
        strcat(json, innerjson);
        strcat(json,"]}}\n");
```

and every time when I print json(variable) in JSP. there's a strange char (what I said above) between `"thumbnails:[here!{".`

I think the `"strcat(json,innerjson)"` part has some problem, but I can not find it.
The other parts are all fine.

Comment: Buffer overrun, undefined behavior, etc. How do you define `json`? Why aren't you using `snprintf()`?

Comment: check buffer size of temp and json buffers

Comment: @H2CO3 I defined json as a char array. its length is 4096 bytes. I didn't know about snprintf. thanks for that:D

Comment: @555k Length of My other char arrays are all 1024. tmp 1024, innerjson 2048, json 4096...